# How to use dict/words?

Tags: 12.04, dictionary

I need to use the file 'words', but I can't find it.

This shows a red file called 'words', which I think is a broken link:

```
ls /usr/share/dict
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

apt-file says it's provided by `wamerican: /usr/share/dict/words`.  I would:

`apt-get install --reinstall wamerican`

Comment: Seems like 'words' is for every word. If you need a specific language you can install for eg: wspanish, and use dict/spanish

Comment: Use `wbritish` for British english.

Comment: On my system (having installed wbritish), `/usr/share/dict/words` is a symlink to `/etc/dictionaries-common/words`, which is itself a symlink back to `/usr/share/dict/british-english`.